# Problem in convert function in react as a class component in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to convert  the function FAQSection to 
class FAQSection

This is for a webapp

```
const handleChange = panel => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };
```

to

```
constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            expanded: 'panel0',
            setExpanded: false
          }
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
handleChange(panel){ 
      this.setState({
      expanded: panel,
      setExpanded: false
    });
   };
```

I want to make ExpansionPanel working with the second handlechange instead of 
the first one from here(https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/)

Comment: can you share  your working code  with https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-khorana-0o5ic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Function.prototype.bind` instead of arrow functions, then you need to bind event handler like below.

```
<button onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this, panel)}>Delete Row</button>
...
handleChange(e, panel) { 
    this.setState({
    expanded: panel,
    setExpanded: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = { expanded: 'panel0' }
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    } 
handleChange(panel){ 
      this.setState({expanded: panel===this.state.expanded?false:panel});    
};
```